# How to replace a word in a string in java without using .replace

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android application wherein I have a paragraph on a label and when the user tapped a word the user can replace that word, my problem is all the words that is similar with the tapped word is being replaced because I'm using .replace , what I need to do is to replace the word that is tapped only.

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: You need to get the `starting point index` and `ending index` in order to manipulate the specific string within a certain string.

Comment: How exactly do you detect which word is tapped?

Comment: I already figure out a solution! Thanks btw, I used, 

indexStart = labelCode.getSelectionStart();
indexEnd = labelCode.getSelectionEnd();

String a = codeText.substring(0,indexStart);
String b = codeText.substring(indexEnd,codeText.length());
String final = a+newVar+b;

@cricket_007 I used Spannable... .getClickableSpan to detect the tapped word

Comment: Cool. You are welcome to answer your own questions below so that others may find your solution later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figure out a solution, I used...

```
int indexStart = labelCode.getSelectionStart(); 
int indexEnd = labelCode.getSelectionEnd(); 
String a = codeText.substring(0,indexStart); 
String b = codeText.substring(indexEnd,codeText.length()); 
String finalAns = a+newVar+b;
```

I used Spannable... .getClickableSpan to detect the tapped word on the label

Answer (score 0):

As Enzokie said earlier, you should take a look at the starting and ending indexes of the word you wish to remove.

If I understand correctly you wish to replace a word the user has selected. The String class has lots of methods that are really helpful with this kind of stuff. What you would want to use is the Java String indexOf(String str) method. This finds the first index of the first occurrence of the word. If you don't want the first occurrence, other methods of similar function are available here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm

Once you have the starting and ending indexes, you can simply place a " " at the positions until the next space(the end of the word).
Then, you could use the String insert() method with the position you found earlier on to place a new word where the old one existed.

Hope this was helpful.